# What would be the order of reactivity of these compounds in Sn1,Sn2,E1 and E2 reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

My problem is that these compounds seem as if their Sn1 and E1 reactivity are identical as the carbocation would of similar nature and stability. For the Sn2 part the first compound seems to have a hindered scope of a frontside attack (due to the tertbutyl group). However the answers given are completely the opposite. I am completely confused.[image]

Comment: Well in both compounds 1 and 2 , the groups attached are the same but they have different stoichiometric alignments. So  in compound 1, the tery butyl and bromine are in different planes due to which there will be less steric hindrance there whereas in case of the second compound, bromine and the tert butyl are in the same plane hence it will provide a higher steric hindrance to the attcking nucleophile.

Comment: @Ritvish How about a backside nucleophilic attack on the compound 2

Comment: Maybe trying to draw the chair form of cyclohexane, then placing $\ce{C(CH3)3}$ group at equatorial position and then checking the positions of $Br$ atom can help...